# FSharp.Data: CssSelect doesn't work as expected

Tags: f#, css-selectors, f#-data

Here a part of my **HTML** (*if need - you can explore it completely [here](https://apteka.ru/search/?q=%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%BF%D0%B0&order=products%2Cmaterials&vendor=)*)

[image: Sample HTML]

I've checked [this examples](http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/HtmlCssSelectors.html) before but when I'm trying to parse `article` elements by

```
doc.CssSelect "article[itemtype='http://schema.org/Product']"
```

or

```
doc.CssSelect "div.items.catalog-items > article"
```

or

```
doc.CssSelect "div.list.catalog-list article"
```

all these give me no results, can't figure out why. Also, even this construction  gives me nothing

```
doc.CssSelect "div.list.catalog-list"
```

But this

```
doc.CssSelect "div.list"
```

returns an element (*but also not what I'm searching*).

**Any supposes?**

Comment: 1) None of your articles have an itemtype attribute 2) article is not a child of div.items.catalog-items - the div.list.catalog-list is the child 3) Not a clue. This should work.

Comment: 1) hmm, I'm confused - copy-pasted html contains `itemtype` attribute - http://take.ms/2dOEY 2) http://rflechner.github.io/ScrapyFSharp/HtmlCssSelectorsExample.html#Practice-1-Search-something-on-Google - take a look at the second example, is `h3` not a child of `div.g`? Here the hierarchy - http://take.ms/wGw1yi

Comment: @BoltClock 2) anyway, with `div.list.catalog-list` is the same thing

Comment: Just use `doc.CssSelect "article"`. It works here: https://try.jsoup.org/

Comment: @Szer it doesn't work also as I've tried. I've tried much more variants than presented in the question.